Problems with implementation of subresultant pseudo-remainder sequence in Sturm's theorem
I've implemented the subresultant pseudo-remainder sequences ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Pseudo-remainder_sequences ) as described in Wikipedia. However, when applying them as in Sturm's theorem to calculate the number of roots, the results are incorrect. According to physical expectations, there should be no roots, which is confirmed through numerical experiments. Yet, the number of roots indicated by Sturm's theorem differs from what the Roots function suggests.
I think not every pseudo-remainder sequence is Sturm's sequence, but I need to somehow modify the sign in the code...
SturmSequence[a_, b_] := 
 Module[{r, d, \[Gamma], \[Beta], \[Psi], i},(*Initialization*)
  r[0] = a;
  r[1] = b;
  \[Psi][1] = -1;
  \[Beta][1] = (-1)^(Exponent[r[0], x] - Exponent[r[1], x] + 1);
  i = 1;
  (*Iteration*)
  While[Exponent[r[i], x] >= 0, 
   d[i] = Exponent[r[i - 1], x] - Exponent[r[i], x];
   \[Gamma][i] = Coefficient[r[i], x, Exponent[r[i], x]];
   (*Update \[Psi] and \[Beta] for i>1*)
   If[i > 1, \[Psi][
      i] = (-\[Gamma][i - 1])^d[i - 1]/\[Psi][i - 1]^(d[i - 1] - 1);
    \[Beta][i] = -\[Gamma][i - 1]  \[Psi][i]^d[i];];
   (*Compute next remainder*)
   r[i + 1] = 
    Simplify[
     PolynomialRemainder[\[Gamma][i]^(d[i] + 1)  r[i - 1], r[i], 
       x]/\[Beta][i]];
   i++;];
  (*Return the sequence*)Table[r[j], {j, 0, i - 1}]]

(*It passed example from wiki:*)

testP1 = x^8 + x^6 - 3  x^4 - 3  x^3 + 8  x^2 + 2  x - 5;
testP2 = 3  x^6 + 5  x^4 - 4  x^2 - 9  x + 21;
(*Compute the Sturm sequence*)
sturmSequence = SturmSequence[testP1, testP2];

(*Verify the last remainder is 260708*)
Assert[Last[sturmSequence] === 260708]

(*I have my polynomial I need to test for roots:*)

P6 = -(729  P^2 + 486  g  P^2 - 405  A  g^2  P  S  x^2 - 54  P  x^3 - 
     72  g  P  x^3 - 18  g^2  P  x^3 + 486  A  g^2  P  x^3 + x^6 + 
     2  g  x^6 + g^2  x^6);
P6Der = D[P6, x]
cl =  SturmSequence[P6, P6Der];
(*A,g,S,P are parameters I will set up later  *) 
cl = SturmSequence[P6, P6Der];
data = {g -> 0.0000013, A -> 2700000, x -> 1.2, y -> 0.92, z -> 1.1};
P6xyz = P6 /. {x -> D} /. {S -> x + y + z, P -> x  y  z} /. data;
Roots[P6xyz == 0, D] (*no real roots*) 
cl /. {x -> 0} /. {S -> x + y + z, 
   P -> x   y   z} /. data (*two sign changes*) 
cl /. {x -> S} /. {S -> x + y + z, 
   P -> x   y   z} /. data (*four sign changes*)

